# How to enable hot swap in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to work on intelliJ on my webapps and I don't know how to hot swap code while working.

For example while I was working in Eclipse when I edited jsp files Eclipse automatically, instantly swapped the file so when I refreshed the page my changes were there

When I change class code in Eclipse it worked a bit longer because he republished the app but did it automatically and instantly.

I saw that intelliJ in the runtime configuration has an option 'how class swap'. I did check it but nothing is happening. I had tried compile, make, save and everything else and nothing is happening. I had to reload the app and I had to do dis manually. Secondly intelliJ reloads EVERY application in my webapp directory. I have them a lot so it taking ages. **how can I turn on hot swap**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hotswap only works in debug mode. So you need to connect to your webserver through a debug configuration. Then, after compile either the project or at least the class with the modifications, IntelliJ tries to hotswap that class.

This only works for minor changes. For example, creating new methods on the fly is not possible using this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hotswap works with exploded artifacts on [Update action](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html). If it doesn't work with your project, [contact support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA) for help and provide the project to reproduce it.